# How is a single threaded server able to cater to multiple clients even thru non-blocking I/O?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, server, nonblocking

When implementing a server, we can delegate one client request to one thread. I read that problem with this approach is that each thread will have its own stack and this would be very "expensive". Alternative approach is that have server be single threaded and implement all client requests on this one server thread with I/O requests as non-blocking request. My doubt is that if one server thread is running multiple client requests simultaneously, won't server code have instruction pointer, set of local variables, function calls stacks for each client request, then won't this again be "expensive" as before. How are we really saving?.

Comment: That single server thread will have only one instruction pointer and a single set of local variables. But, yes, the per-client state has to be remembered which now has to be done using heap objects which can be associated with a particular client. Whether this will really save resources heavily depends on the underlying system and what kind of native resources it will assign to each thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read that problem with this approach is that each thread will have its own stack and this would be very "expensive".

Depends on how tight your system resources are.  The typical JVM stack-space allocated per thread defaults to 1mB on many current architectures although this can be tuned with the `-Xss` command line argument.  How much system memory your JVM has at its disposal and how many threads you need determines if you want to pay the high price of writing the server single threaded.

> My doubt is that if one server thread is running multiple client requests simultaneously, won't server code have instruction pointer, set of local variables, function calls stacks for each client request, then won't this again be "expensive" as before

It will certainly will need to store per request context information in the heap but I suspect that it would be a lot less than 1mB worth of information to hold the variables necessary to service the incoming connections.

Like most things, what we are really competing against when we look to optimize a program, whether to reduce memory or other system resource use, is code *complexity*.  It is harder to get right and harder to maintain.
Although threaded programs can be highly complex, isolating a request handler in a single thread can make the code extremely simple unless it needs to coordinate with other requests somehow.  Writing a high performance single threaded server would be much more complex than the threaded version in most cases.  Of course, there would also be limits on the performance given that you can't make use of multiple processors.

Answer (score 1):

Using non blocking I/O, A single I/O thread can handle many connections. The I/O thread will get notification when:

- client wants to connect
- the write buffer of the socket of the connection has space when the write buffer of the socket was full the previous round.
- the read buffer of the socket of the connection has data available for reading

So the thread makes use of event-multiplexing to serve the connections  concurrently using a selector. A thread waits for a set of selection-keys from the selector, and the selection key contains the state of the event you have registered for and you can attach user data like a 'session' to the selection-key.

A very typical design pattern used here is the reactor pattern.

But often you want to prevent blocking the I/O thread with longer running requests. So you offload the work to a different pool of threads. Then the reactor changes to the proactor pattern.

And often you want to scale the number of I/O threads. So you can have a bunch of I/O threads in parallel.

But the total number of threads in your application should remain limited.

It all depends on what you want. Above are techniques I frequently used while working for Hazelcast.

I would not start to write all this logic from scratch. If you want to make use of networking, I would have a look at Netty. It takes care of most of the heavy lifting and has all kinds of optimizations built in.

I'm not 100% sure if the a thread that doesn't write to its stack will actually consume 1MB of physical memory. In Linux the (shared) zero-page is used for a memory allocation, so no actual page frame (physical memory) is allocated unless the stack of the thread is actually written to; this will trigger a copy on write to do the actual allocation of a page-frame. Apart from saving memory, this also prevents wasting memory bandwidth on zeroing out the the stack. Memory consumption of a thread is one thing; but context switching is another problem. If you have many more threads than cores, context switching can become a real performance problem.